# Create new field in R data.table using RegEx on another field

Tags: r, regex, data.table

Given this `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(f1 =  c(
  "stuffstuff-0000097125",
  "stuffstuff.abc.0006496679",
  "stuffstuff0007517235",
  "stuffstuff_xyz.0007280719",
  "stuffstuff0005995303",
  "stuffstuff_a1b_0000143856",
  "stuffstuff0009362407",
  "stuffstuff.c44_0009735298"
))
```

I *want* to get these results:

```
                          f1 parsed_val
1:     stuffstuff-0000097125        
2: stuffstuff.abc.0006496679        abc
3:      stuffstuff0007517235        
4: stuffstuff_xyz.0007280719        xyz
5:      stuffstuff0005995303        
6: stuffstuff_a1b_0000143856        a1b
7:      stuffstuff0009362407        
8: stuffstuff.c44_0009735298        c44
```

Here is what I tried:

```
rex_pattern <- "(?<=(\\.|\\_|\\-))[A-Za-z0-9]{3}(?=(\\.|\\_|\\-)[0-9]{3,})"

dt[, `:=`(parsed_val = regmatches(f1, regexpr(pattern = rex_pattern, f1, perl = TRUE)))]
```

However, due to recycling, these are the results I am getting:

```
                          f1 parsed_val
1:     stuffstuff-0000097125        abc
2: stuffstuff.abc.0006496679        xyz
3:      stuffstuff0007517235        a1b
4: stuffstuff_xyz.0007280719        c44
5:      stuffstuff0005995303        abc
6: stuffstuff_a1b_0000143856        xyz
7:      stuffstuff0009362407        a1b
8: stuffstuff.c44_0009735298        c44
```

I tried to use `ifelse` in a function to return an empty string:

```
getMmFromFilename <- function(my_file_name){
rex_pattern <- "(?<=(\\.|\\_|\\-))[A-Za-z0-9]{3}(?=(\\.|\\_|\\-)[0-9]{3,})"
nothing_found <- character(length = 0)

mm <- regmatches(my_file_name, regexpr(pattern = rex_pattern, my_file_name, perl = TRUE))
ifelse(identical(mm, nothing_found), "missing_Mm", mm)
}

dt[, .(parsed_val = getMmFromFilename(f1))]
```

But this only returned 1 value of `abc`.  The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/regmatches) for `regmatches` says: " For vector match data (as obtained from regexpr), empty matches are dropped; for list match data, empty matches give empty components (zero-length character vectors)."  I am guessing the solution lies in here, but I have not been able to get it yet...

As for solutions, my workflow requires that I use `data.table`, and a brief explanation of the solution would be a huge help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt[,parser_val:=sub(".*?[._](.*)[._].*|.*","\\1",f1)]
dt
                          f1 parser_val
1:     stuffstuff-0000097125           
2: stuffstuff.abc.0006496679        abc
3:      stuffstuff0007517235           
4: stuffstuff_xyz.0007280719        xyz
5:      stuffstuff0005995303           
6: stuffstuff_a1b_0000143856        a1b
7:      stuffstuff0009362407           
8: stuffstuff.c44_0009735298        c44
```

If you want to use the `regmatches` you can use the `pattern="(?<=[._]).*(?=[._])|$"` with `perl=TRUE`

```
dt[,parser_val:=regmatches(dt$f1,regexpr("(?<=[._]).*(?=[._])|$",dt$f1,perl = T))]
> dt
                          f1 parser_val
1:     stuffstuff-0000097125           
2: stuffstuff.abc.0006496679        abc
3:      stuffstuff0007517235           
4: stuffstuff_xyz.0007280719        xyz
5:      stuffstuff0005995303           
6: stuffstuff_a1b_0000143856        a1b
7:      stuffstuff0009362407           
8: stuffstuff.c44_0009735298        c44
```

Comment: Good thought to use `sub`.  I am still interested in how to return an empty string for non-matching rows in my example above.  I will accept this answer if no others are provided.

Comment: @Stan you will need to use the `extract_string` from `stringr` package which does not drop the empty matches

Comment: @Stan to be able to capture the empty strings, just capture either their end or their beginning.. Thus just add either `|^` or `|$` at the end of your regular expression pattern. This should solve your issue